# Importance of order of authors in published paper when applying for PhD positions

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, authorship

In some subfields of Computer Science, usually the order of authors in papers indicate the importance of contributions of authors to a paper. I am currently contemplating the possibility of pursuing a PhD degree. Accordingly, my question is, when applying for PhD positions, do admission committees consider (and if so, how do they evaluate) the order of authors in papers that I have published. Is the number of papers in which I have been the first author an important factor for admission committees?

Comment: Usually in **some subfields of** computer science... In particular, in my subfield of computer science, authors are always ordered alphabetically.

Comment: @JeffE you are right and I edited my question. In Soft Computing and Machine Learning, authors are not ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends. Authorship order doesn't always indicate who did the most work or the most important work on a paper in many fields. Some fields are alphabetical. Some fields have the lab leader or the person who won the gran *last*. Hopefully the admission committee understands the norms of their own field and the field you are coming from (if they are different) to be able to make a good evaluation.

I've never served on a PhD admissions committee, but I understand that they generally will try to determine your contribution to your publications when evaluating your application.

Comment: In addition to a list of publications you will of course be submitting a resume where you can specifically add your contributions in some or all papers you have published.

Comment: @kabZX, I would probably skip such self-serving statements when looking at a PhDed person's CV unless I was worried about their contribution. I've hired ~20 people into researchy positions over the last dozen years, and while I've skimmed their paper titles, I've never studied the author order carefully.

Answer (score 5):

Primary authorship is best. However, any authorship when applying to a PhD is good.

(Depending on the field and subfield, being listed first indicates being the primary author).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? Is it possible for you to share some of your personal experiences or provide some references?